# Vimeo embedded videos don't show in Safari

Tags: macos, safari

Vimeo embedded videos do not appear in Safari although they appear in all other browsers on the same machine. Not only do the video not play but the placeholder where the video should be on the page is blank. This seems to be Safari 5 related.

Comment: Can you provide an example page with a Vimeo embedded video, so we can try it... I assume you do not mean the Vimeo site itself, since those work fine for me in Safari 5.

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to mind for me is if you happen to have any Extensions installed in Safari. You might consider turning them off and reseting Safari from the Safari drop down in the menubar. Clear out caches and and website data.

If you are familiar with looking at the page source code and know how to enable and understand Safari 5 developer mode and debug features, you will probably be able to get a good amount of information for that. Keep me attuned and all the best!

[Trial video](http://devour.com/video/cinemetrics/)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, Chrome/ Firefox all function fine, but Safari returns a blank space. It works, however, if private browsing is on, but behaves the same (blank) even with a cleared cache/ cookies. Come on Safari, sort this out!

No extensions present, so the fix mentioned didn't work.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/313762)

Answer (score -1):

In my case it was an extension called 'Youtube5'.